# Evento onclick no funciona en Loop [React js]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy consumiendo un API para obtener informacion de un catalogo y posterior a eso cargo la informacion en un componente

el problema que tengo es cuando quiero mandar llamar una funcion con **onClick** en el loop, pero por alguna extraña razon no se ejecuta.

Alguien podria explicar que estoy haciendo mal, soy nuevo en react y seria de gran ayuda

Saludos..

```
state ={ categorias:[] };

componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/categoria').then(response =>{        
        const objcategoria = response.data;
        this.setState({ categorias: objcategoria });
      }).catch(function(err){
          console.log(err);
      });
}

seleccionaCategorias = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
}
```

---

Renderizo la informacion que trae el post

```
 render() {
         const categoria = this.state.categorias.map((cat, index)=>{
             return (<Categorias key={index} 
                                 onClick={() => this.seleccionaCategorias(cat._id) } 
                                 nombreCategoria={cat.categoria}> 
                    </Categorias>)
         });
```

Se pinta la informacion guardada en variable categoria

```
return (
<div className="row">
      { categoria }
</div>
)
```

Mi version de react

```
create-react-app --version  1.5.1
"react": "^16.8.6",
```

Comment: En qué parte estás pintando la información de la variable `categoria`, no me quedó clara esa parte 

Comment: Y si la manera de declarar el evento lo cambias y haces el binding en el constructor???

Comment: Hola Diego, vea que tu codigo no esta mal, pero de todos modos lo hice de una manera diferente, prueba con este ejemplo. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-categorias

Comment: @GermanAlzate al hacer el return { categoria }

Comment: @AlonsoUreña Gracias amigo, esa propuesta me funciono, por que pasa eso??

Comment: Con gusto @DiegoSilva, tal vez sea por un error el component Categorias